# What are the covariant & contravariant forms of four momentum?

Tags: special-relativity, covariance

I have been searching online for these. I found somewhere that momentum components calculated using momentum operators are covariant because gradient transforms in covariant fashion. But I am having trouble finding the contravariant form. From my teacher’s slide, I am giving the two forms provided (I don’t understand these though that’s why asking here):

Contravariant form : [image]

And covariant form: [image]

Someone please help explaining these.

Comment: What part of this don’t you understand? Are you asking whether the red edits are correct?

Comment: Do you understand how to raise and lower indices?

Comment: @Ghoster for instance there should be a minus in the momentum operator expression; also what would the covariant spatial coordinates mean? and what are these two equations meaning physically?

Comment: *there should be a minus in the momentum operator expression* Which momentum operator expression? The one with the red negative sign? If so, I agree, as long as the metric signature is + - - -.

Comment: The usual coordinates $ct,x,y,z$ are the contravariant components $x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3$. The covariant components are defined by lowering the index: $x_\mu=\eta_{\mu\nu}x^\nu$ where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric tensor. If you take this as $\text{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$ then you get $x_1=-x^1=-x$, etc.

Comment: @Ghoster why are we calling them covariants? why would we need these new ‘spatial coordinates’?

Comment: I don’t know what definitions you’ve learned for “contravariant” and “covariant”. When you use the metric to lower a contravariant index you get a covariant index. Having both kinds makes it easy to write Lorentz-invariant quantities without the metric, like $p^2\equiv p^\mu p_\mu=(E/c)^2-\vec p^2=(mc)^2$.